# GPGS Turn-Based Multiplayer - Set participant status?

Tags: android, google-play-games, multiplayer

The question might seem quite odd, but I couldn't quite find an answer perusing the API documentation.

What is the purpose of the participant's status?
Is it possible to manually set the status to finished, so that the active games list would show said game for participant to be finished, rather than calling finishMatch()?

The scenario in mind would involve a game with more than two players. Say player A finishes the game, his status should be set to "FINISHED", while player B and C would still  play, until either one of them finishes, which would trigger the end of the game.

Answer (score 0):

Usually Participant status could be shown in UI. Have you found any API which allows you to change Participant status directly? I think to change it to FINISHED you need to call finishMatch().